# How to find an element with specific text with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, contains, replace

I have a table that shows a month like a calendar. In each cell is a *div.fc-day-number* that contains numerical date, e.g., 1, 2, 3, 4, and so on to 31. Each cell also has an initially blank *div.fc-day-content* where the event data can be appended. I'm using the FullCalendar jQuery script, hence all the "fc-" prefixes in the class names.

Within this calendar are supposed to be links to upcoming events. I have a script that goes through each event to place it on the correct day in the calendar. It goes through each table cell and matches the text of the cell to the event date. An event's date is found in *event.date*.

Right now I have this:

```
var table_cell = $jaer("table.fc-border-separate").find("div.fc-day-number:contains("+event.day+")").siblings("div.fc-day-content");';
```

The problem is that the *:contains* selector is not specific enough. An event on March 3 will also appear on 13, 23, 30, and 31 (basically any date with a '3' in it).

How can I write the code for table_cell to get an exact match for *event.day*?

Comment: Here is my final working code, thanks to Archer: `table_cell = $jaer("table.fc-border-separate")find("div.fc-day-number").filter(function(){
 return $jaer(this).text() == event.day;
}).siblings("div.fc-day-content");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using filter instead, to only return the cells with an exact match...

```
var table_cell = $jaer("table.fc-border-separate").find("div.fc-day-number").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == event.day;
}).siblings("div.fc-day-content");';
```

Comment: I had to change the return line to `return $jaer(this).text() == event.day;` but this solution works, thanks! _text_ needed to be _text()_ and the _$_ had to be _$jaer_ for this particular instance.